# Save a tensorflow.js model in node

Tags: string

I am trying to save a tensorflow.js model I have as a json file but it's not working.

```
var exampleModel = {input:1,name:'model'}
fs.writeFileSync('model.json', JSON.stringify(model,null,2))
//=> '"{\"input\":1, \"name\": \"model\"}"'
```

It's not in json format. I wasted a lot of time trying to manually create a json but that didn't work either and I will have to redo it by copying it to a normal object or something.

Answer (score 0):

Seems noone knows anything about this. The problem was that I was using node and I needed to require "@tensorflow/tfjs-node" underneath my tfjs require line. I had to search for this page specifically as there wasn't anything about it in their documentation: https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/model-save-load.html

Here's another helpful link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-node